# How to have another argument when we alread have *arg in the function?

Tags: python, function, tkinter

I have a code to add rows of entries using a `spinbox`. I have the `update` function to update the changes in the number of rows using the spinbox instantly. Inside this function in the line: `for j in range(3):` number 3 shows the number of columns of the created entries. So, when we change the number of rows, we have 3 columns.

```
import tkinter as tk


class Data:
    def __init__(self):
        self.n_para = tk.IntVar()


class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.minsize(700, 700)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack()

        self.data = Data()

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (PageOne, ):
            frame = F(container, self.data)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

    def show_frame(self, c):
        frame = self.frames[c]
        frame.tkraise()


class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, data):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.data = data

        frame1 = tk.Frame(self, width=200)
        frame1.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.frame2 = tk.Frame(self)
        self.frame2.grid(row=1, column=0)

        frame3 = tk.Frame(self)
        frame3.grid(row=2, column=0)

        label1 = tk.Label(frame1, text="Numeric parameters")
        label1.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=10)

        my_spinbox = tk.Spinbox(frame1, from_=2, to=10, textvariable=data.n_para)
        my_spinbox.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=3)

        self.row_list = []
        for i in range(2):
            entry_list1 = []
            for j in range(3):
                entryX = tk.Entry(self.frame2)
                entryX.grid(row=i + 1, column=j)
                entry_list1.append(entryX)  # Add entry to list
            self.row_list.append(entry_list1)  # Add entry list to row

        self.data.n_para.trace('w', self.update1)  # Trace changes in n_para

    # This function is for updating the number of rows
    def update1(self, *args):
        try:
            para = int(self.data.n_para.get())
        except ValueError:
            return  # Return without changes if ValueError occurs

        rows = len(self.row_list)
        diff = para - rows  # Compare old number of rows with entry value

        if diff == 0:
            return  # Return without changes

        elif diff > 0:  # Add rows of entries and remember them
            for row in range(rows + 1, rows + diff + 1):
                entry_list = []  # Local list for entries on this row
                for col in range(1):
                    e = tk.Entry(self.frame2)
                    e.grid(row=row, column=col)
                    entry_list.append(e)  # Add entry to list
                self.row_list.append(entry_list)  # Add entry list to row

        elif diff < 0:  # Remove rows of entries and forget them
            for row in range(rows - 1, rows - 1 + diff, -1):
                for widget in self.row_list[row]:
                    widget.grid_forget()
                    widget.destroy()
                del self.row_list[-1]

app = SampleApp()
app.mainloop()
```

I wanted to add another argument to `update1` function to get the number of columns. but, I think I have a problem with the concept of `*args`, and how to add another argument to the function.
when I modify the code in the below lines, the code does not work.

```
def update1(self, *args, n_col):
```

and

```
for j in range(n_col):
```

Comment: If you want `n_col` to be a positional argument you need to add it *before* `*args`. Otherwise it can only be passed as a keyword argument

Comment: Just place `n_col` before `*args`, or `def update(self, *args, n_col=None)` (replace `None` by the default value your want)

Comment: @david That's not entirely correct. `def update(self, *args, n_col)` is valid, it just means that `n_col` must be passed as keyword argument

Comment: You can also pass the argument in… it will be contained in the `args` variable that is a list of arguments passed. So you have three options. 1. Pass it in and check for it in the `args` list. 2. Make a new positional arg before the `*args` or 3. Create a named argument after the `*args` that must have a default value and can only be passed in by name.

Comment: Well it does not have to have a default value if you want the names argument to be required to be passed always.

Comment: @DeepSpace thanks for your reply. I test the way you mentioned to bring n_col before `*args` however, I am getting `typeError` : NoneType object is not callable. Is that possible to show me on the code how I can fix it.

Comment: @Jarvis thanks for the reply. I have tried many methods including yours. But I get errors mostly about the `typeError`. Is that possible to how I can fix it in my code.

Comment: `self.update1()` is triggered by `trace()`, so it expects three arguments only.  When you add new argument to it, it will raise exception when it is executed (triggered by update of the tkinter variable).

Comment: @acw1668 Thanks for your reply. Is there a way to make it work as I want it? or I need to have all these lines again with another number of columns?

Comment: What value or variable you will pass as the `n_col` argument when `self.update1()` is executed?  You can use lambda: `self.data.n_para.trace('w', lambda *args: self.update1(x))` where `x` is the value or variable you want to pass, also you need to change definition of `self.update1` to `def update1(self, n_col)`.

Comment: @acw1668 thanks. it worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a fairly simple solution. (i'm kind of guessing a little to what error your having and how your calling the method) if this is not helpful maybe update the question with the errors.

either reverse the order in which you declare *args and n_col or when calling use a named variable.

```
def my_sum(*args, ncol):
    result = 0
    # Iterating over the Python args tuple
    for x in args:
        result += x
    return f"{ncol} + {result}"

print(my_sum(1, 2, 3, ncol=5))

def my_sum(ncol, *args):
    result = 0
    # Iterating over the Python args tuple
    for x in args:
        result += x
    return f"{ncol} + {result}"

print(my_sum(5, 1, 2, 3))

5 + 6
5 + 6
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't know why it is not working on my code. Is that possible to show how I can fix it through my code.

Comment: It is possible to to show but first you must provide details of how exactly it isn't working in your code

Answer (score 0):

The *args argument must be the last in your method input.
Try this:

```
def update(self, n_col, *args):
```

Comment: That's not entirely correct. `def update(self, *args, n_col)` is valid, it just means that `n_col` must be passed as keyword argument

Comment: Yes, you are right. If specifying n_col is always required and we don't want n_col to have a default value, we need to use the code I provided.

Comment: No, that is incorrect. `def update(self, *args, n_col)` does not provide a default value for `n_col` and `n_col` is always required, it just has to be provided as a kwarg. For example `update(1, 2, n_col=3)` or `update(1, 2, 3, 4, n_col=5)`